# Android Realm getInstance performance

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using Realm on Android. Is it an expensive operation to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance();`? Would I be fine calling it each time I want to access the db from my intent service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. Realm uses a lot of caching under the hood, so in most cases calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` is the equivalent of a HashMap lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Realm.getDefaultInstance(); each operations. But you have to sure closed realm when using loop statements.